# XDocument handling of xi:include

Tags: c#

https://www.w3.org/TR/xinclude/#examples

Does anyone know how to handle them in XDocument?

e.g.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<document xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
  <p>120 Mz is adequate for an average home user.</p>
  <xi:include href="disclaimer.xml"/>
</document>
```

I believe there used to be something called XInclude.net, that appears to not exist any more.
I was hoping the functionality was now core XDocument functionality?

Comment: It's not. Markup that attempts to pull in external resources through declarations has been subject to unexpected security vulnerabilities in the past (as these things tend to be easy to abuse outside tightly controlled environments), so I very much doubt this would ever be considered for inclusion (no pun intended).

Comment: yeah...I can see that tbh....I just need to do something like this, and I don't want to reinvent some clunky mechanism to do it

Comment: XML has gone a bit out of fashion as being too clunky and verbose, and I don't think XInclude itself was ever popular. There are lots of markup languages with interpolation features (like mustache.js, Blazor, Jinja, whatnot) but those may not be suitable for your scenario. For scenarios with simple, fixed value replacements (not deeply nested markup or dynamic documents) simple string replacement with explicit and unlikely patterns like `{{ myVar }}` would suffice (taking care to still escape or CDATA the value, of course).

Comment: mines a bit more complex than that....in fact its an xslt file...I could write an xslt to generate an xslt given an xslt as the input..maybe I'll give that a go

Answer (score 0):

thanks to Jeroen Mostert

basically the answer seems to be
"no" due to concerns about security.

I may try to do this with XSLT, and write XSLT templates that generate the required output files (which are xslt files).